# MVC Editor Templates

Tags: mvc-editor-templates

I was trying nested Editor Templates but couldnt get it working. The structure of my model is

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public EmployeeModel Emp { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    public EmpType EmployeeType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public enum EmpType
{
    Manager = 1,
    Assistant = 2,
    TeamLeader = 3
}
```

Each EmpType will have different EditorTemplates
The Index view is

```
@model CompanyModel

<h3>Index</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Emp,"Employee")
```

Then i have create EditorTemplates(Employee.cshtml)

```
@model EmployeeModel


<h2>Employee</h2>

@Html.EditorForModel("EmpType_"+ Model.EmployeeType.ToString())
```

EditorTemplate(EmpType_Manager.cshtml)

```
@model EmployeeModel


<h2>EmpType_Manager</h2>

I am Manager
```

For testing i am populating the model with dummy data in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index(CompanyModel model)
    {
        EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel
        {
            EmployeeType = EmpType.Manager,
            Name = "xxxx",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now,
            EmailAddress = "xxx@yyy.com"
        };
        model = new CompanyModel();
        model.Emp = emp;
        return View(model);
    }
```

When i run this it does not call the EmpType_Manager template. Can some one help me on this. I have tried using partial view which works. But would like to use EditorTemplate instead of Partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like this is not possible as it is by mvc design.